# Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm having the following errors when I run the `SpringBootApplication`:

```
2016-04-23 05:50:24.346  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-04-23 05:50:24.356  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-04-23 05:50:24.385  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-04-23 05:50:24.405 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_i2t738wo4x3tdcmbhqgomubmg
2016-04-23 05:50:24.405 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.423 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_t0dkmpiim1vamsp4gk8prew3n
2016-04-23 05:50:24.423 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.441 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table course drop foreign key FK_cuaoq0uw55jpcfvfhbuii5utp
2016-04-23 05:50:24.441 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.course' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.461 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table course_material drop foreign key FK_bs5094299iyx2d9ljh6i5rc6k
2016-04-23 05:50:24.461 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.course_material' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.481 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table course_material drop foreign key FK_e4tmf79knpcyxjfc41452wtlv
2016-04-23 05:50:24.481 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.course_material' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.501 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table forum drop foreign key FK_rynifmiry638ka6e08avmxl9x
2016-04-23 05:50:24.501 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.forum' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.533 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table mail_box drop foreign key FK_hodc1557iup5oc121suudg5hr
2016-04-23 05:50:24.533 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.mail_box' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.557 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table message drop foreign key FK_2kutjtgfjvk2m3i29668l0n3j
2016-04-23 05:50:24.557 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.message' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.577 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table message drop foreign key FK_lbhyy4gtgh0ojf80bc4aq6x45
2016-04-23 05:50:24.577 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.message' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.599 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table message_mailbox drop foreign key FK_eqau3hwhobsvhxr4b0m2xvuop
2016-04-23 05:50:24.599 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.message_mailbox' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.624 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table message_mailbox drop foreign key FK_d6vn0iflgf9k6jrbsqmwrdxjf
2016-04-23 05:50:24.624 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.message_mailbox' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.641 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table registered_user drop foreign key FK_jxpn3w33nyd74ygfsv0smd2i7
2016-04-23 05:50:24.641 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.registered_user' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.663 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_rating drop foreign key FK_3lpqe9rmerccjerpnxnhyiyhv
2016-04-23 05:50:24.663 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.user_rating' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.685 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_takes_course drop foreign key FK_7ra4qdylay0p2622re8tobacb
2016-04-23 05:50:24.685 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.user_takes_course' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.708 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_takes_course drop foreign key FK_md8p234kyrbc3unoaaqytxpre
2016-04-23 05:50:24.708 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.user_takes_course' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:26.899  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-04-23 05:50:26.952  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5ffb21e1: startup date [Sat Apr 23 05:50:21 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-23 05:50:26.956  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.mycompany.app.controllers.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2016-04-23 05:50:26.956  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/welcome]}" onto public com.mycompany.app.controllers.Welcome com.mycompany.app.controllers.WelcomeController.welcome(java.lang.String)
2016-04-23 05:50:26.957  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-04-23 05:50:26.957  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-04-23 05:50:26.962  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 05:50:26.962  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 05:50:26.968  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 05:50:27.033  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2016-04-23 05:50:27.033  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.033  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.033  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.034  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-04-23 05:50:27.052  WARN 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2016-04-23 05:50:27.076  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-04-23 05:50:27.078  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-04-23 05:50:27.100  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-23 05:50:27.101  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.app.App                    : Storing a few customers...
2016-04-23 05:50:27.431  INFO 11585 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.app.App                    : Started App in 5.693 seconds (JVM running for 773.917)
2016-04-23 05:50:34.376  INFO 11585 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-04-23 05:50:34.376  INFO 11585 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-04-23 05:50:34.398  INFO 11585 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
```

I've seen that there's another similar problem, but I would not know how to solve it anyway. It strange because in some cases the same error seems to appear twice, for example

```
2016-04-23 05:50:24.405 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_i2t738wo4x3tdcmbhqgomubmg
2016-04-23 05:50:24.405 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
2016-04-23 05:50:24.423 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_t0dkmpiim1vamsp4gk8prew3n
2016-04-23 05:50:24.423 ERROR 11585 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
```

Note that apparently this is not affecting for example the responses to a certain URL request...

**Edit**

I forgot to mention. I've all the privileges to delete and create tables in this database. I'm using Spring to recreate the tables, and this is my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://path_to_server/Group2SEA2016
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=my_password

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

With this, I would like to drop the tables everytime before recreating them from the `@Entity` classes...

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange that the error is appearing twice. The error appears one time for each failed operation. There are two different ALTER TABLE statements being executed.

```
: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_i2t738wo4x3tdcmbhqgomubmg
: Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop foreign key FK_t0dkmpiim1vamsp4gk8prew3n
: Table 'Group2SEA2016.comment' doesn't exist
```

The reasons for the error could be exactly what the error message says. It looks like it's referring to table named `comment` in the `Group2SEA2016` database.

It's possible that the table doesn't exist. Or, it might be that the table exists, but the user you are connecting to as doesn't have privileges on the table.

On some MySQL instances, table names are case sensitive. There may be a table name `Comment`, but if the instance uses case sensitive table names, then a reference to table name `comment` won't match.

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to mention (it's late here and I'm tired). I have complete access to the database, i.e. I can delete whatever tables I want. I'm going to edit my questions with more related details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here, seeing my console gave more info before the errors (I'm guessing you only copied the errors and not the info lines that come before), but my errors where the same.
My problem seemed to be that I tried to make columns with a reserved name (like). When I changed that column name, hibernate didn't give any errors anymore and my db was made correctly.